# Running jar from cmd

Tags: java

I have seen a lot of posts and found lots of data on the net about this but I am still confused.

I have downloaded a .jar file and I need to increase its heap size. I have added the jre1.6/bin in the Path of Windows 64 bit and I run from cmd.

The problem arises that it says unable to access jar file.

Can anybody explain in some detail what should I do to run it from cmd. Do i need  to add the location of jar file into the Path too ?? Also I have noticed that in many posts they tell to change the classpath but I have'nt done anything as such.

Do tell if you need any extra information.

------------------------------- (Update)

This is really wierd ..... I did it what was mentioned in here and now the program loads and then exits with Out of memory error saying that it needs more heap size even though it was working before with 128 m heap size. This happens when I increase it to 1024m. Can anybosy explain why the error could have come. I have 3GB Ram so I don't understand it.....

Comment: Tell us the command(s) you've tried...

Comment: show what you've tried so far (include the paths to each of the files)

Comment: 1) what is the exact command you are running?  2) what is the exact output from running that command?

Comment: Okay the file is located at C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6 and what I ran is " java -jar weka.jar ".  I did'nt add quotes in the actual command. This I did from inside the Weka-3-6 directory .  The output is unable to access jar file

Comment: Edit your question using the "edit" link instead of making a comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should run the jar:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar /path/to/the/jar.jar
```

If you are running the command from the directory that the Jar is in, you can just specify it by name.  Otherwise you need to qualify the path to the Jar in order for Java to be able to find it.

Comment: @ jjnguy Thanks a lot ..... your first method did the trick although the running inside the directory one is not working for me atleast.... Thanks....

Comment: Shouldn't the -Xmx argument go before the -jar? Otherwise, it would be treated as being application arguments instead of VM arguments

Comment: @user, you could try running with `./weka.jar`

Comment: Guess you have to specify the full path of the jar file... i.e. the directory can't simply be in your CLASSPATH

Comment: @jjnguy i tried running the jar file without the: "-Xmx1024m".And it worked, So what does "-Xmx1024m" argument do exactly? Because i could run the .jar without it, but it works with it too. Im confused :/

Comment: @LuisAlberto the `Xmx` command tells the JVM to use up to 'm' megabytes of memory. I'm not sure what the default is without using the Xmx flag, but it can often times be too small.

Answer (score 2):

From your "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6" folder:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar weka.jar
```