# Run jar from resources

Tags: java

I have embedded directory with java application in another java apps resources. I am currently able to unpack the required files and run the embedded app with process builder.

Is there any way to run the jar from java without unpacking the files? And specify the class path with jars in resource file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219341/running-jar-from-cmd?rq=1

Comment: Not with the standard class loader. Apparently, it comes down to the fact that [`JarFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) only supports ordinary files as input. You will have to write your own class loader.